# Find $ \lim _{n \to \infty} \int_0 ^ {1} (\frac { 2nx^{n-1}}{1+x})\ $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Find
>   $$\lim _{n \to \infty}   \int_0 ^ {1} \left(\frac { 2nx^{n-1}}{1+x}\right) \mathrm{d}x$$

How to find it? The sequence of function is certainly not uniformly convergent. Should I do it in brute force manner?

Comment: Integrate by parts, ($1/(1+x)$ being the part you differentiate).

Comment: After integrating by parts as mentioned above by Mindlack, apply Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: This is a typical approximation-to-the-identity problem. Roughly speaking, $nx^{n-1}$ approximates the Dirac delta $\delta(x-1)$, and so, the limit is $\frac{2}{1+x}$ evaluated at $x=1$.